# custom validation in rails - select 2 from 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know from looking at the Rails api that there's a way to create custom validations, but I can't figure it how to do it with this.  I want the user to only be able to select 2 of the 4 check_boxes... Pretend the controller is named favorites_controller and the favorites table has these attributes

Is there a way to make them only select 2 of the 4?

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label(:sex, "Sex") %>
    <%= f.check_box(:sex) %> </br>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label(:chocolate, "Chocolate") %>
    <%= f.check_box(:chocolate) %> </br>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
     <%= f.label(:computers, "Computers") %>
    <%= f.check_box(:computers) %> </br>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label(:comicbooks, "Comic Books") %>
    <%= f.check_box(:comicbooks) %> </br>
    </div>
```

@obrok   how far off am I with this function, using a before_save, I know it's not right but can you steer me in the right direction. How do I trigger the validation function on the form submission?  I'm a newbie (and generally not very smart :(

```
before_save :check_box_count

....
    def check_box_count
    @check_box_count = check_box(:sex) +  check_box(:chocolate) + check_box(:computers) + check_box(:comicbooks)
    unless @check_box_count == 2 return false

    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this simply by writing a method which counts how many checkboxes are ticked and then validating that.

Edit:

Something like this I think.

```
validates_inclusion_of :check_box_count, :in => 2..2, :message => "Two checkboxes should be ticked"

...

private 
def check_box_count
  [sex, chocolate, computer, comicbooks].select{|x| x }.count
end
```

Comment: thanks, but I confess I have no idea how to do it. Do you see any potential in the before_save I added in the OP? I don't know how to trigger the validation on the submission of the form. Before_save seems like it might be right, but what do I call the before_save function? and is that function how you'd write it?

Comment: Your before_save method doesn't actually add a validation to the model: try taking a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations  6.2 Custom Methods

Comment: How does the method in this answer get triggered on submission of the form? does the method name need to be included in the form somehow? I looked at the rails guides but I'm such a newbie, it's really confusing. My model is called "guess" and the controller is "guesses". Can you suggest anything?

Comment: It gets triggered when saving the model. The line `validates_inclusion_of :check_box_count` makes sure that is the case. It basically tells the model that a field named `check_box_count` needs to be validated. While it's technically a method, fields are just a kind of method in ruby, so that's not a problem. So in effect the output from the method `check_box_count` if validated for inclusion in the range `2..2`.